# O plot está diferente dos valores da função

Tags: r

Olá, eu plotei no `Rstudio` a função `fdp.GUCU` abaixo, que é uma distribuição normal (0,1) quando x está entre -1 e 1, e uma Cauchy (0,1) fora desses limites. O problema é que o gráfico `plot` não corresponde aos valores desta função.

Visualmente, o gráfico está plotando no ponto 0 apenas parte da função; apenas `exp(-((0)^2)/2)/sqrt(2*pi) = 0.3989423`, sendo que `fdp.GUCU(0)=0.2194183`.

Alguém já viu algo semelhante e saberia o porquê?

```
fdp.GUCU <- function(x){
  if(x>-1 && x < 1){
    (0.55)*exp(-((x)^2)/2)/sqrt(2*pi)
  }else{
    (1.249042)*1/(pi*(1+(x)^2))
  }
}

x <- seq(-4,4, by=0.1)
plot(x, fdp.GUCU(x), type="l", ylim = c(0,0.4))
```

Comment: Eu nunca tinha visto algo semelhante. Executando teu código em partes descobri que para todo o vetor x, a função fdp.GUCU está caindo no else, mesmo nos valores para o qual não deveria. Não sei te dizer o motivo.

Comment: Donde vêm os fatores `0.55` (Normal) e `1.249042`(Cauchy)?

Comment: Essa distribuição vem do artigo Understanding some long-tailed symmetrical distributions (Rogers e Tukey, 1972)

Answer (score 6):

O problema está na utilização de `&&` em vez de `&`. Da documentação, `help('&&')` (ênfase minha.):

> `&` and `&&` indicate logical AND and `|` and `||` indicate logical OR. The
>   shorter form performs elementwise comparisons in much the same way as
>   arithmetic operators. The longer form evaluates left to right
>   **examining only the first element of each vector. Evaluation proceeds
>   only until the result is determined**. The longer form is appropriate
>   for programming control-flow and typically preferred in `if` clauses.

Tradução Google, edita por mim. Ênfase minha.

> `&` e `&&` indicam E lógico e `|` e `||` indicam OU lógico. A forma
>   mais curta realiza comparações elementares da mesma maneira que os
>   operadores aritméticos. A forma mais longa avalia da esquerda para a
>   direita **examinando apenas o primeiro elemento de cada vetor. A
>   avaliação prossegue apenas até o resultado ser determinado**. A forma
>   mais longa é apropriada para programação  de controle de fluxo e
>   normalmente preferida em cláusulas `if`.

Ou seja, a sua função, ao utilizar `&&` só avalia `x[1]`. Como determina imediatamente o valor lógico, `FALSE` ou `TRUE`, segue para o ramo apropriado. Ora, `x[1]` é o primeiro valor de `seq(-4, 4, by = 0.1)`, e é tomado o segundo ramo, correspondente à distribuição de Cauchy.

A solução é quase sempre utilizar a **forma vetorizada** de `if/else`, que é `ifelse`, e da operação lógica, `&`. É isso que o código da 2ª versão da função faz.

```
fdp.GUCU <- function(x){
  if(x>-1 && x < 1){
    (0.55)*exp(-((x)^2)/2)/sqrt(2*pi)
  }else{
    (1.249042)*1/(pi*(1+(x)^2))
  }
}
fdp.GUCU2 <- function(x){
  ifelse(x > -1 & x < 1,
         0.55*exp(-(x^2)/2)/sqrt(2*pi),
         1.249042/(pi*(1 + x^2))
  )
}

x <- seq(-4, 4, by = 0.1)
plot(x, fdp.GUCU(x), type="l", ylim = c(0, 0.4))
lines(x, fdp.GUCU2(x), col = "red", lty = "dotted")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Edição.

A função abaixo utiliza as funções do R base diretamente e dá os mesmos resultados que a minha `fdp.GUCU2`.

```
fdp.GUCU3 <- function(x){
  ifelse(x > -1 & x < 1, 0.55*dnorm(x), 1.249042*dcauchy(x))
}

x <- seq(-4, 4, by = 0.01)

plot(x, fdp.GUCU3(x), type="l", ylim = c(0, 0.4))
lines(x, dnorm(x), col = "blue", lty = "dashed")
lines(x, dcauchy(x), col = "red", lty = "dotted")
legend(x = "topright", legend = c("OP", "Normal", "Cauchy"), 
       col = c("black", "blue", "red"), lty = c("solid", "dashed","dotted"))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: É que no artigo Understanding some long-tailed symmetrical distributions (Rogers e Tukey, 1972) é inventada essa distribuição com proporções de 0,6930665 *normal (0,1) em [-1,1] e 1,0537015*Cauchy fora desse intervalo, (essa densidade fica conectada, descobri hoje) e eu estava verificando outra proporção antes, essa que eu apresentei 0,55 e 1,25 que faz com que a densidade integre 1 também. Muito muito obrigada!!!

Comment: @TaináCaldas Editei com a nova função corrigida, com `dnorm` e `dcauchy` fica muito mais legível. E mudei a sequência `x` para ter mais pontos no gráfico.

Answer (score 3):

O que acontece é que seu `if` só dá uma resposta, `TRUE` ou `FALSE`, porque ele lê a lista toda de uma vez. Como todos os elementos não atendem as condições a comparação resulta em `FALSE` e vai direto pro `else`.

Você tem que fazer a função ser aplicada para cada elemento, aí o `if` é testado para cada valor do vetor. Você pode fazer isso com uma das funções da família `apply` ou um `for`. Aqui tá com o `sapply`, que aplica a função e devolve um vetor de mesmo tamanho.

```
fdp.GUCU <- function(x){
  if((x>-1) && (x < 1)){
    (0.55)*exp(-((x)^2)/2)/sqrt(2*pi)
  }else{
    (1.249042)*1/(pi*(1+(x)^2))
  }
}

x <- seq(-4,4, by=0.1)
y <- sapply(x, fdp.GUCU)
plot(x, y, type="l", ylim = c(0,0.4))
```